# Android Proguard problems(duplicate) when adding Facebook sdk & Google Firebase sdk

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, gradle, proguard

It builds ok but when I run it gets this error:
it didn't happen until I add firebase

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't
>   write
>   [/var/android_projects/Aflam/Aflam/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/debug/jars/3/1f/main.jar]
>   (Can't read
>   [/home/omar/.android/build-cache/7b35109bbea465da27464678b5f699568c4204d8/output/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry
>   [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzw$zza.class]))

```
Proguard rules:
{

    -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
    -keep class com.google.android.gms.**

    -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
    -dontwarn com.google.ads.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
    -dontwarn android.net.**

    -dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
    -dontnote org.apache.http.**
    -dontnote com.android.net.http.**
    -dontnote android.net.**
}


dependencies {

    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile(name:'unity-ads',ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `play-services-ads` has version `8.4.0` in `audience-network-sdk` module with dependencies to `com.google.android.gms` of lower version, exclude `play-services-ads` and add `play-services-ads:10.2.0` afterwards :

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    compile(name:'unity-ads',ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
}
```